# c++ how to use try catch and reexecute the program?

Tags: c++

I have this:

```
int main() {
    try {
         cin >> op;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e) {
         cout << "Por favor indique um valor válido!!!";

    }
}
```

And I wanted that when it enters the catch, the program to be reexecuted, so that it would ask for a new value to the user.

Comment: @MadPhysicist did tell you how. You need to use a loop which keeps looping until it's told to stop looping (e.g., `do { ... } while(...);` or `while(...) { ... }` loop)

Comment: wich means I need to use throw , so that my do...while gets that value thrown to know how to stop right?

Comment: You have your solution but I would not recommend this. Exceptions in C++ should not be used to change the control-flow of your program. If you expect a wrong value by the user such that you would want to give him another chance to enter it, it is not really an exception. It is not always easy to see but this seems like a scenario where exceptions should not be used

Comment: ok, do you recomend another way? or isn't it possible?

Comment: @IceFire. Agreed. However, `while ! ./a.out; do :; done` in bash would work fine in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I wanted that when it enters the catch, the program to be reexecuted, so that it would ask for a new value to the user.

You can put a loop around your try catch block:

```
int main() {
    bool have_invalid_argument = true;
    while(have_invalid_argument)
        try {
            cin >> op;
            have_invalid_argument = false;
        }
        catch (invalid_argument& e) {
            cout << "Por favor indique um valor válido!!!";

        }
    }
}
```

You should note though that

```
cin >> op;
```

usually won't throw that exception.

You rather should go with [std::basic_ios::exceptions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) and [std::ios_base::failure](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure) to detect input parsing errors.

---

How to fix that?

**Option 1**

Don't use exceptions at all:

```
  while(!(cin >> op)) {
      cout << "Por favor indique um valor válido!!!";
      cin.clear(); // Reset the failure state
      std::string dummy;
      cin >> dummy; // consume the invalid input

  }
```

**Option 2**

Set the exception flags and catch the appropriate exceptions

```
int main() {
    cin.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
    bool have_invalid_argument = true;
    while(have_invalid_argument)
        try {
            cin >> op;
            have_invalid_argument = false;
        }
        catch (std::ios_base::failure &fail) {
            cout << "Por favor indique um valor válido!!!";    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and where do i put those?

Comment: @RuiEmanuelQuaresma You set the exception mask flags, and catch _the appropriate_  exceptions in another `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

did it this way (it's a way to go around it)

```
char op ;
int flag = 1;
do
{

    cout << "Indique a opção que corresponda ao exercicio desejado: " << endl << "1 - ex1.1;" << endl << "2 - ex1.2;" << endl << "3 - ex1.3;" << endl << "4 - ex1.4;" << endl << "5 - ex1.5;" << endl << "6 - ex1.6;" << endl;
    cin >> op;

    if (op == '1' || op == '2' || op == '3' || op == '4' || op == '5' || op == '6') {

        flag = 0;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Por favor indique um valor válido!!!";
    }



} while (flag == 1);
```